# Too many cod-parts in jad file

Tags: blackberry, ota, jad, .cod-file

I created a blackberry application but I am having problems publishing it on my web site. I have uploaded the jad, jar, alx and cod file (from which I extracted the whole content). I also added the missing MIME types. But when I try to download the application by requesting the jad file, I get a 500 error with the details saying that the file myproject-30.cod is missing.

So I looked at the list of cod file... sure enough, they go from 0 to 29. No 30, 31 or above. However, in the jad file, there are references for cod files for up to 110.

My question is: how can I configure eclipse to produce the jar file properly? Or, alternatively, how can I modify the jad file to delete references to the 30+ cod files? Or maybe it is that the cod file is missing files?

Comment: Just a quick comment - if you have that many COD files for your application it is probably in the "multi-megabyte" range for size.  That's pretty big and if it's a consumer app you may lose some users simply due to limited space on the device.  You may want to consider reducing the size of images or audio by lowering the quality, or by creating a different build for each device and exclude the media (images, etc.) that aren't needed for that screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the JAD file was not recreated by the rapc compile tool. Basically, it was created a couple of week ago and that's it, so clearly it was not up-to-date. To force the eclipse plugin to recreate the file, I simply deleted it. The new file is now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with [blackberry ant tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/main), task will look like this:

```
<target name="produce_ota">
   <mkdir dir="${ota.dir}" />
   <jadtool input="your_app_name.jad" destdir="${ota.dir}">
       <fileset dir="${build.dir}" includes="*.cod" />
   </jadtool>
</target>
```

This will produce all needed cod parts and jad file to *${ota.dir}* assuming there will be built application in *${build.dir}* directory.

Check out slashdev.ca tutorial - [Blackberry development with Ant & Eclipse](http://www.slashdev.ca/2007/05/30/blackberry-development-with-ant-eclipse/)